# Change Textbox value after selection from Dropdownlist

Tags: vb.net, textbox, dropdown

When I select a value from the first dropdownlist, it populates the second dropdownlist and textbox to their correct values. However, when I select a different value from the second dropdown, the textbox value still retains the same value from which it was populated with. Could anyone please point out what I am doing wrong?

```
 If ds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(3).ToString = "M" Then
            DropDownList2.Items.Insert(0, "Member")
            DropDownList2.Items.Insert(1, "Non-Member")
            DropDownList2.Items.Insert(2, "")
            TextBox1.Text = "M"
        ElseIf ds.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(3).ToString = "NM" Then
            DropDownList2.Items.Insert(0, "Non-Member")
            DropDownList2.Items.Insert(1, "Member")
            DropDownList2.Items.Insert(2, "")
            TextBox1.Text = "NM"
        Else
            DropDownList2.Items.Insert(0, "")
            DropDownList2.Items.Insert(1, "Member")
            DropDownList2.Items.Insert(2, "Non-Member")
            TextBox1.Text = ""
        End If



        If DropDownList2.SelectedValue = "Member" Then
            TextBox1.Text = ""
            TextBox1.Text = "M"
        ElseIf DropDownList2.SelectedValue = "Non-Member" Then
            TextBox1.Text = ""
            TextBox1.Text = "NM"
        Else
            TextBox1.Text = ""
 End If
```

Comment: Hi, am I wrong or do I see only one dropdownlist ("DropDownList2")? But anyway, why are you using `f DropDownList2.SelectedIndex = "Member" Then` on the one Hand and `ElseIf DropDownList2.SelectedValue = "Non-Member" Then` on the other Hand. It might run above If, ElseIf, Else Statement.

Comment: I use it so when the ddl and textbox are populated and you want to change the value of the ddl, the textbox's value should change. The 1st ddl is used as the protected sub. So ddl2 is dependent on ddl1's selection.